# How to animate drawable through object animator

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, objectanimator

I am trying to scale a vector drawable with the help of `ObjectAnimator` based on state of button is selected or not. I a trying to do this as,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_map_colored"
        android:state_selected="true" >
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="150"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="2"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="5000"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="2"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_map" android:state_selected="false" >
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="150"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="5000"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Simply I am trying to increase scale on select of image and to decrease scale on deselect imageview. But above code is not working, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="150"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="5000"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="150"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="5000"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

then call like below code..

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet)  AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.sample);
set.setTarget(fab); // set the view you want to animate
set.start();
```

Comment: OP wants the animations to be triggered on selecting and deselecting the view though